# What control style is this?

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, winapi

I want to make a control where the bottom is nice and beveled as seen here:
http://img19.imageshack.us/f/finalzh.png/

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/f/finalzh.png/](http://img19.imageshack.us/f/finalzh.png/)

What style must I add to my control to achieve the same look as this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a static control with a WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE or WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE extended style, and place it in a containing child window, which clips the top and sides so you only see the bottom bevel.

Looking at the picture, you may even not need the child window - just position the static window at -4x-4 (use GetSystemMetrics SM_CX_BORDER to find out the real size of the window border) and size it 2x the border width larger that needed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Windows' default controls. I suspect that's being drawn by that specific application in question.

Comment: @User146780: Not really because that's not a Win32 control you've circled. The standard Win32 tab control only draws the area directly above the controlled area. That said, it doesn't look like complicated drawing -- it's only a 3 color gradient. You can get the same behavior with a few calls to LineTo in your WM_PAINT handler.